# Flash not working on Chrome, FF, Safari, but it is working on IE

Tags: html, css, flash, google-chrome

I made the huge mistake of getting a template instead of just doing the development my self.  Now I've narrowed down the issue-  first, I thought it was an issue with the actual flash file.  Now I'm realizing it's every time I change the images in the HTML editor which just makes no logical sense to me.  This is the code for the flash file:

```
<body id="page1" onload="new ElementMaxHeight()">
   <div id="main">
   <!-- header --> 
   <div id="header">
      <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/…; width="940" height="417"></object><!----> <![endif]-->
   </div>
   <!-- content --> 
   <div id="content">
```

Again, it works great on IE, but nothing else, which is a twist I haven't seen online.

Appreciate any feedback you can offer.

Comment: You can remove that coding from the comments, I edited your question.. also, whats up with the endif.. pretty sure that is the problem. It might be an IE related condition.

Comment: Thanks Josh- can you please update the code to this (I keep making changes to try and make sure it works and want to stick with what they delivered):

Comment: <body id="page1" onload="new ElementMaxHeight()">
<div id="main"><!-- header -->
<div id="header"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,24" width="940" height="417"></object><!----> <![endif]--></div><!-- content -->
<div id="content">

Comment: Alright, updated. Also, can you please provide a live link to the site? That would be helpful

Comment: The reason that it works in IE is because you are using `<object>` tag. That is specifically how you embed Flash for IE. For all the other browsers you use the `<embed>` tag. When coding it by hand, you use both tags together, and nest the embed tag inside the object tag. However, most everyone just uses SWFObject (a Javascript library) to embed flash (and so we don't have to worry about it). I'd post an example as an official answer, but I'm on a phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this answer is here already but i will post a generic code i always use.
Just place the whole block and change related values, swf properties.

```
     <object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="950" height="377">
         <param name="movie" value="myMovie.swf">
         <param name="quality" value="high">
         <param name="wmode" value="direct" >
         <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
         <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
         <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
         <param name="SCALE" value="noborder">
         <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
             <!--[if !IE]>-->
         <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myMovie.swf" width="950" height="377">
         <!--<![endif]-->
         <param name="quality" value="high">
         <param name="wmode" value="direct" >
         <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
         <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
         <param name="SCALE" value="noborder">
         <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
         <div>
         <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
         <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
     </object>
```